SqlRowSet throws Invalid SQL type for column with dateTimeOffset(Type associated with java Instant)
I have upgraded my application to Springboot 3(Hibernate 6) and now instant is stored as datetimeoffset in sql server. I have several queries which returns last modified date and created date using SqlRowSet. Problem is with this approach a method(checkColType ) is called internally which uses java.sql.Types.class which doesn't have any field for datetimeoffset(-155 sqlType) because of this checkColType throws an exception.
Is there any way it can be solved or should i return back to older datatype(datetime) for java Instant.
public class RowSetMetaDataImpl implements RowSetMetaData,  Serializable {
private void checkColType(int SQLType) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class<?> c = java.sql.Types.class;
        Field[] publicFields = c.getFields();
        int fieldValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < publicFields.length; i++) {
            fieldValue = publicFields[i].getInt(c);
            if (fieldValue == SQLType) {
                return;
             }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
    }
    throw new SQLException("Invalid SQL type for column");
}
}

Even in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SSType DATETIMEOFFSET is mapped with microsoft.sql.Types.DATETIMEOFFSET which is absent in java.sql.Types and RowSetMetaDataImpl  uses only java.sql.Types.
Codes Intent: Our team has written various adhoc native sql queries, whose result set we write in excel. Using SqlRowSet we get column meta data and write header even if data is not present. If data is present then data is also written on excel. It is impossible for our team to re-write queries on so many clients. I am also attaching the method which we use to write data.
public Path exportDefaultView(List<QueryExcelSheetConfig> queryExcelSheetConfigs) throws Exception {
    Workbook wb = new Workbook();
    Path temp = Files.createTempFile("temp", ".xlsx");
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(temp)) {
        wb.getWorksheets().removeAt(0);
        for (QueryExcelSheetConfig queryConfig : queryExcelSheetConfigs) {
            String sheetName = queryConfig.getSheetName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9._]+", "_");
            Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().add(sheetName);
            SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("dynamic query from db",
                    queryConfig.getArguments());
            SqlRowSetMetaData metaData = sqlRowSet.getMetaData();
            Cells cells = ws.getCells();
            IntStream.range(0, metaData.getColumnCount()).forEach(colNum -> {
                Cell cell = cells.get(0, colNum);
                cell.setValue(metaData.getColumnName(colNum + 1));
            });
            while (sqlRowSet.next()) {
                IntStream.range(0, metaData.getColumnCount()).forEach(colNum -> {
                    Cell cell = cells.get(sqlRowSet.getRow(), colNum);
                    setCellValue(cell, colNum + 1, sqlRowSet, metaData);
                });
            }
            wb.getWorksheets().get(sheetName).autoFitColumns();
        }
        wb.save(temp.toString());
    } finally {
        wb.dispose();
    }
    return temp;
}


I would say that the type should probably be mapped to java.time.Instant. Isn't that working? And do you have to use that column type checking routine (which you know to be incomplete)?

SqlRowset is kind of weird class to use IMHO, it's more for when you want to transport your resultset somewhere else. How does your fetching code looks?

@g00se i am not calling column type checking routine it was automatically called by javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl 's method setColumnType.

@siggemannen i have updated the use case(code's intent ) in question please take a look.

Yeah, you should just rewrite it using regular query or the callback variant, no need for rowsets here

I'll second that. Rowsets are really a kind of detached and transportable ResultSet

@siggemannen didn't understand what you mean by callback variant. I can't use regular query because I need headers even if there is no data returned by query. Although I reused a method which uses ResultSet and returned a record which has data as well as column's name. Updated the my solution in question. Still wondering why java.sql.Type is outdated even with java 21.

Yeah, your solution is what i ment :) I think the problem is that RowSet is a "cmmon" class which cannot possibly support custom datatypes from all kind of JDBC implementations, it must know about all types because it is kind of "serializeable" resultset, so it must always be able to serialize the object. While ResultSet is more flexible, and it's up to consumer to handle columns properly. Maybe i'm mistaken, i'm not a java language designer :)

I think that some drivers provide their own RowSet implementations (from my memory microsoft jdbc did) which avoids this issue, but anyway, it's the wrong class to use for your task anyway because you don't transport the data anywhere

I can't use regular query because I need headers even if there is no data returned by query. I would check that assumption. afaik, an empty ResultSet should still contain metadata

@g00se JDBC doesn't define support for java.time.Instant, so trying to use that would be highly driver-dependent.

@MarkRotteveel, OK. It seems mighty difficult even to find the JDBC spec...

@g00se You can download it from Oracle, or locate it through jcp.org, i.e. JSR-000221 JDBCTM API 4.3 Maintenance Release 3, that page is is also linked from the java.sql package javadoc

I used this method to resolve my issue.
public ResultRecord executeSelectSqlQueryForResultRecord(String query, Map<String, Object> data) {

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate loadBalancedDB = getLoadBalancedDB();
loadBalancedDB.getJdbcTemplate().setQueryTimeout(SELECT_QUERY_TIMEOUT);
loadBalancedDB.getJdbcTemplate().setFetchSize(1000);

boolean enableAllResultSet = data != null && data.containsKey("enableAllResultSet");
final ResultRecord result1 = loadBalancedDB.query(query, data, rs -> {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    Map<String, Object> values = null;
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>(columnCount);
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        columns.add(JdbcUtils.lookupColumnName(rsmd, i));
    }
    
    List<Map<String, Object>> result = new LinkedList<>();
    int count = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        values = new LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<>(columnCount);
        count++;
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            values.putIfAbsent(columns.get(i-1), JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(rs, i));
        }
        result.add(values);
        if (count > 50000 && !enableAllResultSet)
            break;
    }
    rs.close();
    return new ResultRecord(result, columns);
});

if (result1.result().size() > 50000 && !enableAllResultSet) {
    throw new DataException("Result set size cannot be greater than 50000. " + "Please pass \"enableAllResultSet\" as one of the argument to disable this check.");
}

return result1;
}

